# HBASE REST API PUT Call NOT Updating Record

Tags: rest, hbase, stargate

I tried The following Curl command using the PUT method as mentioned in the documentation. But even after getting a 200OK response, My Data is not getting updated in the Hbase table.

 `curl -vi -X PUT \
          -H "Accept: application/json" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          -d '{"Row":[{"key":"NzAx", "Cell": [{"column":"Y2FzZUR", 
              "$":"QUJD"}]}]}' 
           "https://hadoop.example.com:17001/table/rowkey" -k`

And to the following Curl I get a 200OK response but in my table, No Update happens.

- About to connect() to hadoop.example.com port 17001 (#0)
- Trying [IP Address here]...
- Connected to hadoop.example.com (IP Address) port 17001 (#0)
- Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
- skipping SSL peer certificate verification
- SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- Server certificate:
- subject: CN=Pushkar,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Un...
- start date: May 17 06:43:16 2018 GMT
- expire date: Aug 15 06:43:16 2018 GMT
- common name: Pushkar
- issuer: CN=Pushkar,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Un...

  > PUT /table/rowkey HTTP/1.1
  >   User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
  >   Host: hadoop.example.com:17001
  >   Accept: application/json
  >   Content-Type: application/json
  >   Content-Length: 145
- upload completely sent off: 145 out of 145 bytes
  < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  < Content-Length: 0
  Content-Length: 0
  <
- Connection #0 to host hadoop.example.com left intact

Comment: did you check if the column timestamp is updated or still old?

Comment: @NishuTayal I found out that we were using a custom timestamp, which was larger than the Unix Millisecond timestamp. Thanks for the help! :D